# How to Accessing Type Signature for debuging purposes in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When running spark from spark-shell, when each defined variable created the shell prints out the type signature of that variable along with the toString of the instance.

how can i programmatically generated the same signature without using the shell (for debugging purposes to a log or stdout/stderr) from a spark script or class?

example code run in spark shell (see bold output below)

---

### code:

```
val data = Array("one", "two", "three", "two", "three", "three")
val dataRdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val dataTupleRdd =  dataRdd.map(word => (word, 1))
val countsRdd = dataTupleRdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
countsRdd.foreach(println)
```

---

code run in spark shell (see the output below: i want to generate that from the api):
example type information i want to generate (in logs or output):
**Array[String]**
**org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]**
**org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]**

---

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val data = Array("one", "two", "three", "two", "three", "three")
data: Array[String] = Array(one, two, three, two, three, three)

scala> val dataRdd = sc.parallelize(data)
dataRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> val dataTupleRdd =  dataRdd.map(word => (word, 1))
dataTupleRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:28

scala> val countsRdd = dataTupleRdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
countsRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[2] at reduceByKey at <console>:30

scala> countsRdd.foreach(println)
(two,2)
(one,1)
(three,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard for me to understand because it implies that you need to wait until runtime to see what you have. That isn't the case in a statically-typed language like Scala. You can explicitly type your values yourself (by using your IDE if necessary) and see precisely what you have at *compile* time.

So if types are all you care about, the Scala language (along with your IDE to help you reason about things) has you covered. However, `RDD`s also offer the `toDebugString` method, which describes `RDD`s and their dependencies. This can be very useful for debugging--particularly in identifying the specific type of `RDD` you are dealing with. But it doesn't tell you the contained types because you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `getClass.getSimpleName` to get the readable name for logging, e.g.:

```
val data = Array("one", "two", "three", "two", "three", "three")
print(data.getClass.getSimpleName)     // Output: String[]
```

Also, if you are using intelliJ, you can simply use command + P to check the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are right in saying this shouldn't normally be necessary, you can do it:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def typeName[A](x: => A)(implicit tag: WeakTypeTag[A]) = tag.toString
```

By-name parameter (`=> A`) ensures it can be safely called e.g. on `foo(x, bar(y))` without actually evaluating `bar` or `foo`, or on lazy values. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html for more about `TypeTag`s.